Как зацикливать код в Питон использую библиотеку vk_api
Столкнулся с проблемой, код врубается и через 5 секунд выключается, искал на разных порталах, не нашёл как зацикливать код
Кто знает подскажите, либо подскажите почему код выключается (ошибок нет)
    import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotlongpoll, VkBoteventtype

def send_message (to_user_id, message):
    vk_bot.method ("messages.send", {"user_id": to_user_id, "message": message "randing_id": 0})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Получить токен доступа для сообщества
    vk_bot = vk_api.vkapi (token = "token")

    # Создать объект BOT Longpoll
    longpoll = VkBotlongpoll (vk_session, "group_id")

    # Слушайте новые сообщения
    for event in longpoll.listen ():
        if event.type == VkBoteventtype.message_new:
            message = Event.obj.Text
            from_user_id = event.obj.from_id

            if message == "Start":
                send_message (from_user_id, "Hi")


Для зацикливания используется цикл. Что бы подсказать, почему ваш код "выключается" - нужен код, а его нет

vk_session не определенна
